# Ошибка при преобразовании типа данных nvarchar к datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть хранимая процедура, которая должна изменять данные в таблице, но при её выполнение она крашит и выдаёт ошибку.

Вот код процедуры:

```
USE [Shrtly]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_AlterMovie]    Script Date: 18.06.2017 16:19:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AlterMovie] 
    @original_language as int ,
    @original_title as nchar(100),
    @title as nchar(100),
    @poster_path as nchar(100),
    @release_date as datetime,
    @movie_id as int
AS

UPDATE movie
    SET original_language=@original_language,original_title=@original_title,title=@title, poster_path=@poster_path,release_date=@release_date
    where movie_id = @movie_id

    RETURN @@identity
```

Выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

```
сообщение: 8114, уровень: 16, состояние: 5, процедура: sp_AlterMovie,
строка: 0 [строка начала пакета: 2]
Ошибка при преобразовании типа данных nvarchar к datetime.

(строк обработано: 1)
```

Таблица movie:

[image: movie]

Как это чинить?

### UPD:

пока чинил, нашел, что у меня объявляется @release_date как datetime, а в таблице date, заменил на date. В итоге эта ошибка пропала но появилась новая:

Выполнение процедуры:

```
USE [Shrtly]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_AlterMovie]
        @original_language = 3,
        @original_title = N'hdf',
        @title = N'hgd',
        @poster_path = N'hgd',
        @release_date = 2001-12-21,
        @movie_id = 17

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Новая ошибка:

> Сообщение 102, уровень 15, состояние 1, строка 11 Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "-".

Comment: Похоже, что тип данных передаваемого значения не совпадает с типом данных в таблице. Покажите структуру таблицы Movie

Comment: А какие параметры передаёте процедуре? скорее всего в @release_date передается неправильный параметр. Покажите, как Вы выполняете процедуру.

Comment: пока чинил, нашел, что у меня объявляется @release_date как datetime, а в таблице date, заменил на date. В итоге эта ошибка пропала но появилась новая (в вопросе подробно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дату нужно ставить в кавички:

```
@release_date = '2001-12-21'
```